# Worfklow signature line not configured correctly?

Tags: 2013, workflow, sharepoint-online

I created a signature workflow for an excel sheet. Basically, the workflow tells people they need to fill out their portion of the excel sheet. However, I'm getting this message when I'm testing the workflow. I'm putting my name in every step of the workflow, if that has anything to do with it.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried testing your workflow using more than just your name, such as with 1 or 2 additional test accounts?

Comment: No I haven't. I was worried this might be part of the problem. Do you have to set up a digital signature? I guess I don't know what it looks like when it actually works. I thought you had to buy a digital signature certificate first.